# How to install iTunes 10.7 on OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, itunes, upgrade

I have OS X 10.5.8 on a 2.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo Mac, and I need to install iTunes 10.7 but it won't let me. I need to connect my iPad 4 and iPod nano to iTunes but it won't allow me unless I can upgrade to iTunes 10.7.

Does anyone have had the same problem but managed to overcome it?

Comment: What does "it won't let me" mean? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes 10.7 requires OS X 10.6.8 or later:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1576?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US